# Calling a method inside getDerivedStateFromProps in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Before upgrading react to version `16.3`, I'd call a method based on changes in props like this :

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   if(this.props.country.length !== nextProps.country){
    doSomething(); //example calling redux action
    }
}
```

`componentWillReceiveProps` is unsafe on Version `16.3` and we must use [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops). However, this method returns an object and I don't know how I can call a method from inside it the same way I do with `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: Why don't you use `componentDidMount` for this case? It's better to place this logic there

Comment: yest but as I know `componentDidMount` is for initializing not for when something changes during application life cycle.

Comment: Similar issue - [here](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/721), no need of using `getDerivedStateFromProps` in this case

Comment: @Reason maybe you meant `componentDidUpdate` ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, you need to return an object, which is the new state that that is derived from `nextProp`. According to docs:

> `getDerivedStateFromProps` should return an object to update state, or null to indicate that the new props do not require any state updates.

**But** since you are not updating your state in any way inside your `componentWillReceiveProps`, you should use `componentDidUpdate` instead of `getDerivedStateFromProps`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  if ( prevProps.country !== this.props.country.length ) {
    doSomething(); //example calling redux action
  }
}
```

Comment: If I want to set state and call an ajax function then what is best?

Comment: @Shamseer It is good to use componentDidUpdate for state updates and ajax calls. 
getDerivedStateFromProps was designed to be very minimal, pure and mostly avoid adhoc requirements. Again, the motivation from the React engineers is to encourage isolation and write pure functions.
Reference: https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/721#issuecomment-581479874

Answer (score 9):

For this situation, it was good for the OP to use `componentDidUpdate` but I found myself needing `getDerivedStateFromProps` so I had to make my custom function static as well and call it using the class' name inside `getDerivedStateFromProps`. Something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const something = ClassComponentName.runThisFunction();
    this.setState({ updatedSomething: something });
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.key !== prevState.key) {
        return { 
            updatedSomething: ClassComponentName.runThisFunction()
        };
    }
    return null;
}

static runThisFunction() {
    //do stuff and return value
}
```

To clarify, this is updating the component's state on load as well as when new props arrive. This definitely took me back to my typed-language days. Hope it helps!

Comment: "ClassComponentName" refers to the name of the class that defines the current component being used (i.e. For a class component defined with: [class DeviceSelector extends React.Component {...], the static function would be called as 'DeviceSelector.runThisFunction()'). Another potentially useful resource: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13037

Answer (score 8):

if you need to call a function in "getDerivedStateFromProps", you can put this function in state in constructor , then get this function in "getDerivedStateFromProps" from state.

put function in state in constructor:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      func1:this.func1.bind(this)
   }
}
```

get function from state in getDerivedStateFromProps:

```
getDerivedStateFromProps(props,state){
   return {
       model:state.func1(props.model)
   }
}
```

Comment: its good for times when you have a lot of code in the getDerivedStateFromProps method and you want to have a more readable code and separate to different functions.